# Powerful computer freezing up when opening certain programs and going fullscreen

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

This issue has been happening since I installed the Windows 10 Creators Update (I think). I installed it really late, so I'd say about 2 months ago. Here's what happens:

1. I open the program
2. My mouse starts to slow down (chopping)
3. Sound on Skype/Teamspeak/Discord starts to lag
4. Complete freeze and I have to force shutdown using the button on my PC

It happens in programs like:

1. World of Warcraft
2. Netflix (from Microsoft Store)
3. Plex (from Microsoft Store)

However, here are some even more weird issues:

1. If I right click on the WoW executable, select the `Troubleshoot compatibility`, then hit `Troubleshoot program`, then select the `The program opens but doesn't display correctly` and `The program requires additional permissions`, then hit `Next` and finally `Test the program`, World of Warcraft works just fine. If I then save those settings and open WoW normally the next time, it doesn't work. I HAVE to do that every time.
2. When I open Netflix or Plex, the movies play fine and everything seems fine. When I hit "Fullscreen" (in either one), it starts freezing my PC up like before.

I have tried Windows Update, reinstall GPU drivers (first using Display Driver Uninstaller), updated everything for my Z170 motherboard, and so on. I have tried basically everything but a reinstall of Windows (that would be my very, very last option).

My specs are: i7 6700k, GTX 1080 Ti, 32GB 2666 MHz RAM, and 2x Samsung EVO 860 in RAID 0. Those are the important ones, at least. What can I do next, except reinstall Windows again, which I'd rather not do?

Comment: What do you have for a power supply?

Comment: @computercarguy A 750W from Cooler Master. I am 100% sure it's not a hardware issue, however.

Comment: I'm just trying to rule out the hardware option, too.  I've found that by starting at the hardware level, you can be more certain when ruling things out.  I guess I should have also asked how old your PSU is.  As they get older, they tend to output less power.  I would guess your other components aren't very old, so the shouldn't even be dusty.  Smoking around your computer can make dust stick that much more readily, though.

Comment: How old are your fans?  I've had a fan short out and cause power issues before, and power issues can cause all kinds of weirdness.  I'm not familiar with Win 10 Creators Update, so I can't help there.

Comment: @computercarguy I knew 100% this wasn't a hardware issue. There's just no way it can be, when it's consistently happening in only a few applications. It has been fixed now, though.

Comment: I've seen hardware issues that seemed to be "just 1 or 2 apps", but it was just those 1-2 apps that pushed the right set of circuits past their limits, causing the problems.  I've seen more veteran techs than me spend hours and days re/installing software that ended up being a hardware issue.  After 15 years of experience, I know to test the hardware first, then test software, then test everything again when/if you still can't find the issue.  :-)  Glad you found your solution, though!

Comment: @computercarguy If it really was a hardware issue, it would be caused a lot more times than simply opening something like Netflix or WoW. There should (and probably is) not a difference in hardware than running another game or another application than the ones I mentioned, so I knew 100% it wasn't a hardware issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by reinstalling .NET Framework 4.7.1. Who would've known.

Comment: @computercarguy I know, right?

Comment: I think I would have considered DirectX before a .Net framework.  Maybe you did, but still, weird.

Comment: @computercarguy For it to be DirectX, it would mean Netflix and Plex would also run it. I doubt they run DirectX, but rather something like OpenGL instead.

Comment: I was trying to remember OpenGL, but had a brainfart, so just posted the comment anyway.  :-)